# ps3 applications development

Tags: playstation3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PlayStation3 application development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802349/playstation3-application-development)

hi everybody,these forums said that the only way to develop ps3 games is through linux,can anyone tell about this elaborately,ie what tools needed for the developement.

thanks.