# ps3 applications development

Tags: playstation3

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PlayStation3 application development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802349/playstation3-application-development)
>   [ps3 applications development.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820847/ps3-applications-development)

After we install Linux on a PS3, what tools are needed to develop applications (or) games on Linux? Can someone please clarify this?